# Designing my program to avoid having to cast from base to derived class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism

Ok, I seem to be requiring forward casting from base to derived and I think it might be a design problem so I will explain what I’m doing and you can tell me what I need change. 
XML file defines a bunch of objects that are similar. They share the same base class. The main function is defined in the base class DoWork() and it’s virtual.

My program loads XML file and creates the derived classes and assigns them to a vector of type base class.

Everything is great the program works. I can iterate through the vector and call DoWork();

Now, I’ve added a GUI layer so you can modify the objects and write back a XML file. So, now my GUI code has access to the vector of base class pointers. But, this is no good because I need the info from the derived class so I can write out the XML file. Is the only solution to this dynamic casting? Could I have changed the design somehow? I know casting from base to derived is frowned upon.

EDIT: My GUI needs to display information that the derived class has as well. Just having a serialize class is not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different approaches that you can take here. The first one is providing a virtual method that generates the XML corresponding to the element.

The second approach is providing a visitor interface: basically you define a virtual method that accepts a `visitor` type. The visitor type will be called with the current object at each level of the hierarchy, generating a type of double dispatch mechanism. This way the virtual dispatch will resolve to the most derived object, that will call upon the visitor object to serialize itself.

The first approach is simpler, while the second has the advantage of a looser coupling between each object in the hierarchy and the actual serialization format. That is, you can produce different visitors that can serialize to different formats without having to modify code in your current hierarchy.

Comment: +1, I am pretty amazed this is the only solution so far (out of 6) mentioning Visitation.

Answer (score 4):

Could you add e.g. a virtual `serialize` method to each class, so that your output loop can just iterate through the vector, and call `(*it)->serialize()` on the base pointer for each element?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a method in your base class that prints the object to XML, then have all your derived classes provide their own implementation of it. Basically, you'd be delegating printing to the derived classes.

EDIT: or more generally, follow Oli's suggestion and write a `serialize()` method for your base class that returns an easily digestable collection of that object's important data elements (for instance, a list of key-value pairs). Your main program can then iterate over each object's serialized form and decide what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Post a small code sample -
2. Sounds like the base class needs a virtual WriteXML() - sheer guessing at this point

Answer (score 0):

Either implement a function in the base-class that derived-classes can override to expose the necessary information to write out the Xml, or have the object itself persist to Xml.  Both of these solutions do not necessitate you needing to know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the same behavior in the base class that you need to use to get data in the derived class then you can treat all objects the same. For derived classes that did not previously have this behavior you can have them fail silently. Look at the intention of the composite design pattern.